# How to get multiple value on UILabel from UITableView in Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uilabel

I am new in iOS and I am facing problem regarding to get the multiple value in the UILabel from UITableView. My code is like this

```
#pragma  mark - Complaints Assigned Connection Method
//Connection Method and Delegate...
-(void)serverconnection{


    NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
                             "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
                             "<soap:Body>"
                             "<Method xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">"
                             "</Method>"
                             "</soap:Body>"
                             "</soap:Envelope>"];



    NSURL *myNSUObj=[NSURL URLWithString:@"URL"];
    // NSURLRequest *myNSURequestObj=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myNSUObj];

    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:myNSUObj];
    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[soapMessage length]];

    [theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest addValue: @"http://tempuri.org/Method" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    myNSUConnectionassignedObj=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    NSLog(@"Data =%@",myNSUConnectionassignedObj);
    if(myNSUConnectionassignedObj)
    {

        NSLog(@"successful connection");
        myNSMDataassignedFromServer=[[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{

        [myNSMDataassignedFromServer setLength:0];

}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{


        [myNSMDataassignedFromServer appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{



        NSXMLParser *myNSXMLParserassignedObj=[[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:myNSMDataassignedFromServer];
        myNSXMLParserassignedObj.delegate=self;
        [myNSXMLParserassignedObj parse];
        NSLog(@"%@",myNSXMLParserassignedObj.parserError);
        idassignedarray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        if(myNSUConnectionassignedObj == nil)
        {
            assignedtable.hidden=YES;
        }

        idassignedarray=[responseassigneddict valueForKey:@"abc"];
        NSLog(@"Result Array =%@",idassignedarray);
        // [myDataNSMArray addObject:idassignedarray];
        shortnameassignedarray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        shortnameassignedarray=[responseassigneddict valueForKey:@"abcid"];

    [assignedtable reloadData];

}
#pragma mark - NSXMLParsing Delegate

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"FillBlocksNew"])
    {
        myDataClassObj=[[mydata alloc]init];
    }
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{

    myMutableStringassignedObj=[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:string];
    NSLog(@"Array String: %@",myMutableStringassignedObj);
    NSData *data = [myMutableStringassignedObj dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    responseassigneddict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
    NSLog(@"JSON DATA = %@",responseassigneddict);
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    NSLog(@"DataArray: %@",myDataNSMArray);
}



#pragma mark - TableView Delegate

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
        return [idassignedarray count];

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

        static NSString *STI=@"STI";
        AssignTableViewCell *cell = (AssignTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:STI];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AssignTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
            cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }
        cell.newlbl.text=[idassignedarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        return cell;

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

        return 1;

}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    [[assignedtable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];

    activityid.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[shortnameassignedarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
```

Its output is look like this

[image]

In UILabel I am getting only one value. The first value get overwrite to it.How to get multiple selected id in the UILabel. Thanks in Advance!

My Code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

        static NSString *STI=@"STI";
        AssignTableViewCell *cell = (AssignTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:STI];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AssignTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
            cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }

        cell.newlbl.text = [idassignedarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        if ([cellSelected containsObject:cell.newlbl.text]){
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        }
        else{
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }

        return cell;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    [[assignedtable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];

    activityid.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[shortnameassignedarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    activitytxt.text=[idassignedarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



    static NSString *STI=@"STI";
    AssignTableViewCell *cell = (AssignTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:STI];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AssignTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }



    if ([cellSelected containsObject:cell.newlbl.text]){
        [cellSelected removeObject:cell.newlbl.text];
        NSString *str = [cellSelected componentsJoinedByString: @","];
        NSLog(@"String value is =%@",str);

    }
    else{
        [cellSelected addObject:cell.newlbl.text];
        NSString *str = [cellSelected componentsJoinedByString: @","];
        NSLog(@"String value is =%@",str);

    }


}
```

Comment: so you need to create the array of selected cells string ?

Comment: when you want to show selected value on label ? is there any button ? and how you want to show multiple value on label ? I mean comma separated ? or anything else ?

Comment: @Lion Yes it should be with comma separated on UILabel. In Didselected method of UITableView.

Comment: you need comma separated values of selected cells ?

Comment: @vaibhav Yes I need.

Comment: inside the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method ? please explain bit more so can deliver a solution.

Comment: @vaibhav I need to get multiple value in UILabel like "1,2,3" and I an using NSXMLParsing.

Comment: okay last time, finally you need comma separated values of selected cells or anything else?

Comment: @vaibhav Yes I need comma separated values of selected cells

Comment: @Muju please accept ans if useful so same reflect the other users.

Answer (score 0):

Your `didselectRowAtIndexPath` should be like,

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


[[assignedtable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];

NSArray *indexPathForSelectedRow = [assignedtable indexPathsForSelectedRows];

 NSString *str = [[NSString alloc]init];

for (int i = 0; i < indexPathForSelectedRow.count; i++) {

     NSIndexPath *iPath = [indexPathForSelectedRow objectAtIndex:i];


    [str stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,",[shortnameassignedarray objectAtIndex:iPath.row]]];




}

if (str.length > 0) {

     str = [str substringToIndex:[str length] - 1];
    activityid.text= str;
}


}
```

and make sure that multiple selection is enable for your `tableview`!!

Comment: I am getting nothing on label. And when I scroll UITableView selection get removed

Comment: set `assignedtable.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;` in viewDidload then try!

Comment: In str it Shows "object returned empty description"

Comment: make sure `shortnameassignedarray` have string objects and it is not nil and make sure you are getting indexpaths in `indexPathForSelectedRow` array! and take new update also of answer!!!!! It was a little mistake!

Comment: "Printing description of indexPathForSelectedRow:
<__NSArrayI 0x7fcc3b4a4e70>(
<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000008016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1},
<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000018016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 3}
)" value of IndexPath

Comment: Are you there.I am not getting what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in 2 ways.

1) append all text content in one larde NSString. You can assign that to the text label. By setting the number of lines to 0, you can use large strings.

2) the other way, probably what you want, is changing the cell in the table. By changing or creating a new cell type. This allows you to add more UILabel's (and other types) in one cell.